# How to share specific div with content using Facebook Share button

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm triying to share a div with content using the facebook share button. But I'm not getting any luck. Does anyone have any idea or some clue to get this? My implementation is sharing my webpage but not my DIV with specific content.

**Connection:**

```
<?php
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MY_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'SECRET_ID',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $albumjson = $facebook->api('/me/albums');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    $user = null;
  }
}
?>
```

**Printing results:**

```
<div id="divToShareOnFacebook">
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < count($albumjson['data']); $i++) {  
$albumId = $albumjson['data'][$i]['id'];
$photos = $facebook->api("/{$albumId}/photos"); 
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Code? does your `div` contains HTML tags?

Comment: No, I don't think code is necessary here, I have the connection and everything is working but Facebook button is sharing the entire website. Do I have to set html tags inside the div? Can you explain me more please?. I've found some of 'meta property=go:image' and set an image but is for the general page. Is there any other tag that I should put inside the 'div'?

Comment: _"I don't think code is necessary here"_, ok, simple answer Facebook shares `URL`s not a snippet of page! you have to use OG meta tags found [here](http://ogp.me)

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, hope you are not upset. I've edited my question. Hope you can help me. I'm checking the url that you provide me.